# After Migrating Bootstrap 3, bootstrap style validation has broken Asp.net MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, unobtrusive-validation

I cannot get nice red border around the errors when validation is required after upgrading from Bootstrap 2.3.2 to Bootstrap 3.

I have changed my forms as bootstrap has dropped 'controls' class and changed control-group to form-control as below:

From

```
  <div class="control-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ForeName, new { @class = "control-label" })
        <div class="controls">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ForeName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ForeName)
        </div>
    </div>
```

TO

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ForeName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-6">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ForeName, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ForeName)
    </div>
</div>
```

Before when the user fails to fill the Name on submission the user was seeing the following :

[image]

after upgrade :

[image]

I have done some search on the internet and I found [here](http://www.benripley.com/development/javascript/asp-mvc-4-validation-with-bootstrap-3/) it explains to get the validation working again.

it says in description that "we need to hook into the jQuery model validation library used by MVC. The following script can be added to your validation bundle to apply the Bootstrap css classes."

I have created a validation.js with the js provided in the webpage and bundled that to my website. I viewed the source code and I cna see that it gets loaded.

But I still cannot get the validation working?

what am I missing here?

Jquery version 1.11.1.js

here is the my validation.js :

```
 $(function () {
    // any validation summary items should be encapsulated by a class alert and alert-danger
    $('.validation-summary-errors').each(function () {
        $(this).addClass('alert');
        $(this).addClass('alert-danger');
    });

    // update validation fields on submission of form
    $('form').submit(function () {
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            $(this).find('div.control-group').each(function () {
                if ($(this).find('span.field-validation-error').length == 0) {
                    $(this).removeClass('has-error');
                    $(this).addClass('has-success');
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            $(this).find('div.control-group').each(function () {
                if ($(this).find('span.field-validation-error').length > 0) {
                    $(this).removeClass('has-success');
                    $(this).addClass('has-error');
                }
            });
            $('.validation-summary-errors').each(function () {
                if ($(this).hasClass('alert-danger') == false) {
                    $(this).addClass('alert');
                    $(this).addClass('alert-danger');
                }
            });
        }
    });

    // check each form-group for errors on ready
    $('form').each(function () {
        $(this).find('div.form-group').each(function () {
            if ($(this).find('span.field-validation-error').length > 0) {
                $(this).addClass('has-error');
            }
        });
    });
});

var page = function () {
    //Update the validator
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
            $(element).closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-success");
        },
        unhighlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
            $(element).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-success");
        }
    });
    } ();
```

Thanks

Comment: can you post a fiddle with the resulting wrong html?

Comment: I found the issue. I should have put the validation.js at the bottom of the layout instead of the top. Thanks

Comment: Then please post your solution as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue like you so have built a bootstrapped themed validation summary panel which works with bootstrap 3.1.1

I have recently just added support for unobtrusive validation and all it requires is one change to the standard jquery.unobtrusive.js file that is described in my wiki for styling only.

https://github.com/JellyMaster/MVCBootstrap

https://github.com/JellyMaster/MVCBootstrap/wiki/BootStrapped-Validation-Summary

edit: noticed you sorted your issue but hope this helps others.

edit 2: As I wasn't happy with the unobtrusive support I have removed it for now. I will update this post once I have come up with a better solution. Thanks Erik for the feedback.

Comment: I would suggest NOT altering jquery.unobtrusive.js, since this file is updated from time to time, and you will have to remember to re-apply your changes every time it's updated.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch As I said the change is purely for cosmetic effect all other functionality is left as is. It is purely to put the "list-group-item" class onto the appended li's. If there is a better way of doing this then I am open to ideas.

Comment: My concern is that people will copy your approach, and not realize that when they use nuget to update files, they will lose these changes... and they may have forgotten they added them, or they may have been added by someone else a long time earlier.  It's almost always a bad idea to alter files that are distributed via nuget.  If you absolutely have to, copy the file to a different name, and remove the nuget package (although you will not be able to take advantage of bug fixes, new features or even security flaw fixes if you do this).

Comment: You may find this project helpful http://www.nuget.org/packages/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.bootstrap/

Comment: @ErikFunkenBusch this was an approach I took this evening on my project. I'm still not happy with the way it is implemented so I may pull the feature (it has that bad code smell about it). I will certainly look into that alternative suggestion. It also relies in having the CSS classes that are included in the default mvc 4 template.